# Live Agent REST and CORS

Tags: rest, liveagent

I am trying to create a chat client using the SalesForce Live Agent REST API but I am running into an issue with CORS. Does the REST API support JSONP, if so do you have some examples, if not then what would be the proper way to use the Live Agent REST API with JavaScript? I am currently using a proxy I quickly created on my server but this causes a few other issues.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. The Live Agent REST API was not designed with browser clients in mind, for that you would be expected to use the Deployment/Pre-Chat APIs.

You can see an example of the REST API usage here

https://github.com/pepefloyd/LiveAgentChatClient